# undefined reference errors when I add boost log dependecies

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to add boost logging functionality.

But I've got a lot of errors with `undefined reference`.

```
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(core.o): In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::implementation::thread_data>::~thread_specific_ptr()':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(core.o): In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::implementation::thread_data>::get() const':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:84: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(core.o): In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::implementation::thread_data>::reset(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::implementation::thread_data*)':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:105: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(record_ostream.o): In function `get':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:84: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(record_ostream.o): In function `reset':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:105: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(record_ostream.o): In function `get':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:84: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(record_ostream.o): In function `reset':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:105: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(record_ostream.o): In function `~thread_specific_ptr':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(severity_level.o): In function `void boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit<boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::checked_deleter<unsigned long long>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<unsigned long long*> > > >(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::checked_deleter<unsigned long long>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<unsigned long long*> > >)':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:861: undefined reference to `boost::detail::add_thread_exit_function(boost::detail::thread_exit_function_base*)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(once_block.o): In function `boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry::wait(boost::detail::timeout)':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/win32/condition_variable.hpp:94: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::interruptible_wait(void*, boost::detail::timeout)'
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0\bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi/libboost_log-mgw51-mt-d-1_58.a(thread_id.o): In function `at_thread_exit<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::this_thread::(anonymous namespace)::id_storage::deleter>':
D:\c++\boost_1_58_0/./boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:861: undefined reference to `boost::detail::add_thread_exit_function(boost::detail::thread_exit_function_base*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My linked libraries looks like this.

[image]

My `include` declarations looks like this

[image]

Also my boost `include` folder is located in main `x86_64-w64-mingw32` include folder

Comment: I don't think it's our problem, but Boost log actually have *two* linker libraries, the `boost_log` library which you already link with, but also `boost_log_setup`.

Comment: I never claimed that it's your problem. Though I indeed forget to add `setup` library

Comment: Maybe try changing the link order so that boost_thread is linked after boost_log.

Comment: @melak47: Yes, this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540171/boost-log-gcc-4-4-and-cmake

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error under Windows 10, Cygwin GCC setup. I had to link boost_thread separately in addition to boost_log and boost_log_setup.

```
-lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_thread
```

I was using BOOST 1.66.